# Can you truly explain multimode optical fiber in the ray picture?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

When I studied wave guides I understood multimode and single mode guides as consecuences of maxwell equations, latelly I have been reading about multimode fiber in a more technical context and it seems some people understand multimode fiber in the ray picture but I dont seem to understand how it is explained, I get that the bigger the core diameter the wider variety of angles it can accept and this intuitivelly correlates with multimode fiber but I don't think you can explain it in the ray picture (how can you see the change in $v$ number that signals the transition from single mode to multi mode?)